# swiftUI tabbar is visible where it shouldn't be

Tags: swiftui, toolbar, visibility, tabbar

I have a TabView in SwiftUI and I want to hide the system Tabbar to implement my own. When I try to hide the tabbar it works until I switch the tab. The tabbar is then visible although the tabbar is explicitly set to hidden. Is it a SwiftUI bug? Here is the example code with which it can be adjusted:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tabViewSelection: Int = 1

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabViewSelection) {
            Color.red
                .frame(height: 1600)
                .onTapGesture {
                    tabViewSelection = 2
                }
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                }
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)

            Color.green
                .frame(height: 1600)
                .onTapGesture {
                    tabViewSelection = 1
                }
                .tag(2)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "cart")
                }
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        }
    }
}
```

It should always hide the system tabbar

Comment: First of all, this seems like a bug. Second why would you disable the TabBar, this seems anti Apples Human Interface Guidelines. Third, if you want it custom, check out Youtube videos like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_KZwX-yP4o